# MySQL error InnoDB: Warning

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Why is this error occurring?

```
2017-06-15 05:54:42 1848 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2017-06-15  5:54:42 6216 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Did you change anything on this server before this started happening?  Did you have any issues, like a forced power off or any kind of crash?

Answer (score 1):

I have been having a similar problem after switching from mySql to MariaDB, and some of the error listed in your output were the same. I hope my solution is relevant to you as well (as you did not give much context about the problem).

My problem was that I did not initialize the database user with the following command:

```
$ mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

After running this, I solved the error

```
[ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
```

and when I started the db again, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I was having exactly the same issues as you (my log has some different stuff in it). But MySQL (actually MariaDB in my case) was failing to start, with the same `[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB`. I resolved it by adding this line to the config (either at the end of an existing `[mysqld]` section, or add a new section with that header):

```
default_tmp_storage_engine = InnoDB
```

And that seemed to solve it for me. MySQL now starts fine...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the MySQL server was being configured with too big buffer pool size (running on virtual machine with too little memory - just 2GB RAM)

```
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
InnoDB: mmap(1117782016 bytes) failed; errno 12
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2018-11-13 17:06:19 7882 [ERROR] Aborting
```